# Primefaces fetch dropdown values on show

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dropdown

I have a strange situation where one needs to dynamically populate dropdown values. The best idea I have come up with is creating a button, which triggers ajax request that fetches new dropdown values and on complete updates the dropdown and displays it.

I was wondering if there is any other more elegant way of handling situations like this. I am using the latest primefaces version 11.0.0.

Comment: You could use `p:autoComplete` instead. Useful for large data sets, but also if the data set might have changed since the page was rendered.

Comment: And `p:autoComplete` has a dropdown mode if you still want it to "look" like a dropdown.  https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the `p:autoComplete` component with the `dropdown` attribute set to `true` instead. It allows you to get the values when the button is clicked or when a query is typed. You don't need to take care of updating the component yourself. The only thing you need to do is have a `completeMethod` in your bean or have a `completeEndpoint` (REST endpoint).

With PrimeFaces 12 you can even (re)use a `LazyDataModel` as a suggestions provider.